# Hide some controls of Spark VideoPlayer on my Flex project

Tags: apache-flex, hide, controls, flex-spark, video-player

I want to remove (hide) some controls of my videoPlayer on my flex project.
They just Marked in this picture:

[image: Remove marked controls from my videoPlayer]

For example I can use `videoPlayer.scrubBar.visible = false` to hide the scrubBar, but if I use it for *fullScreenButton* although this will hide it, but the place of button will remain empty! Or I don't know how remove or hide *currentTime* / *duration*.

P.S: prefer to don't use the **skin**, because it's a pretty simple project and I don't want to increase my classes and etc...

Comment: What VideoPlayer component are you using?  If you're using the Spark VideoPlayer component; then creating a custom skin is the proper approach.

Comment: Yes. I'm using _Spark VideoPlayer component_. There is no simple way instead of creating skin? like `videoPlayer.control.visible = false` ?!

Comment: Creating skin is a simple way. Your idea with accessing inner parts of the component and playing with its properties is not a simple way, it is unreliable. You will pay twice if you use such dirty approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extend the VideoDisplay component--and create a custom skin--to make these skin Parts easily hidden / displayed at runtime if you wish.  Or you could access the skin parts directly and change the visibility property.

But, the best way to do this is to build a custom skin.  Here is one that took me a couple of minutes and accomplishes everything you ask.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--

    ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
    Copyright 2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated
    All Rights Reserved.

    NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
    in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.

-->

<!--- The default skin class for the Spark VideoPlayer component.  

     @see spark.components.VideoPlayer

      @langversion 3.0
      @playerversion Flash 10
      @playerversion AIR 1.5
      @productversion Flex 4
-->
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" alpha.disabledStates="0.5" 
    chromeColor.fullScreenStates="0xCCCCCC">
    <!-- A chrome color of 0xCCCCCC in the fullScreenStates means we ignore the chromeColor property 
         all together as 0xCCCCCC is essentially just a no-op color transform -->

    <!-- host component -->
    <fx:Metadata>
        /** 
         * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.VideoPlayer")]
    </fx:Metadata>

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        <![CDATA[
            /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. */
            static private const exclusions:Array = ["videoDisplay", "playPauseButton", "scrubBar", 
                                                     "currentTimeDisplay", "timeDivider", "durationDisplay", 
                                                     "volumeBar", "fullScreenButton"];

            /**
             * @private
             */
            override protected function initializationComplete():void
            {
                useChromeColor = true;
                super.initializationComplete();
            }

            /**
             * @private
             */
            override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array 
            {
                return exclusions;
            }

            /**
             * @private
             */
            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
            {
                dropShadow.visible = getStyle("dropShadowVisible");

                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            }
        ]]>

    </fx:Script>

    <!-- states -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="uninitialized" stateGroups="uninitializedStates, normalStates" />
        <s:State name="loading" stateGroups="loadingStates, normalStates" />
        <s:State name="ready" stateGroups="readyStates, normalStates" />
        <s:State name="playing" stateGroups="playingStates, normalStates" />
        <s:State name="paused" stateGroups="pausedStates, normalStates" />
        <s:State name="buffering" stateGroups="bufferingStates, normalStates" />
        <s:State name="playbackError" stateGroups="playbackErrorStates, normalStates" />
        <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledStates, normalStates"/>
        <s:State name="uninitializedAndFullScreen" stateGroups="uninitializedStates, fullScreenStates" />
        <s:State name="loadingAndFullScreen" stateGroups="loadingStates, fullScreenStates" />
        <s:State name="readyAndFullScreen" stateGroups="readyStates, fullScreenStates" />
        <s:State name="playingAndFullScreen" stateGroups="playingStates, fullScreenStates" />
        <s:State name="pausedAndFullScreen" stateGroups="pausedStates, fullScreenStates" />
        <s:State name="bufferingAndFullScreen" stateGroups="bufferingStates, fullScreenStates" />
        <s:State name="playbackErrorAndFullScreen" stateGroups="playbackErrorStates, fullScreenStates" />
        <s:State name="disabledAndFullScreen" stateGroups="disabledStates, fullScreenStates"/>
    </s:states>

    <!-- drop shadow -->
    <!--- @private -->
    <s:RectangularDropShadow id="dropShadow" blurX="17" blurY="17" alpha="0.32" distance="4" 
                angle="90" color="#131313" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" 
                excludeFrom="fullScreenStates"/>

    <!--- Video and player controls are clipped if they exceed the size of the 
          component, but the drop shadow above is not clipped and sizes to the component.
          We also set verticalScrollPosition so that when we do clip, rather than clipping  
          off the bottom first, we clip off the top fist.  This is so the player controls 
          are still visible when we start clipping. -->
    <s:Group id="clippedGroup" clipAndEnableScrolling="true" left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0" 
             verticalScrollPosition="{Math.max(0, 184-clippedGroup.height)}">

        <!-- There's a minimum size for the video and controls.  If we go below that
             we are clipped. -->
        <s:Group minWidth="263" minHeight="184" left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">

            <!-- background when the videoDisplay doesn't fill its whole spot -->
            <s:Rect bottom="1" left="1" right="1" top="1"
                    bottom.fullScreenStates="0" left.fullScreenStates="0" 
                    right.fullScreenStates="0" top.fullScreenStates="0">
                <s:fill>
                    <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" />
                </s:fill>
            </s:Rect>

            <!--- @copy spark.components.VideoPlayer#videoDisplay -->
            <s:VideoDisplay id="videoDisplay" bottom="24" left="1" right="1" top="1" 
                            bottom.fullScreenStates="0" left.fullScreenStates="0" 
                            right.fullScreenStates="0" top.fullScreenStates="0" />

            <!-- video player controls -->
            <s:Group left="0" right="0" height="24" bottom="0" bottom.fullScreenStates="150">

                <!-- actual controls with a maxWidth in non-fullScreen mode -->
                <!--- @copy spark.components.VideoPlayer#playerControls -->
                <s:Group bottom="0" horizontalCenter="0" left="0" right="0" maxWidth.fullScreenStates="755" id="playerControls">

                    <!--- @copy spark.components.VideoPlayer#playPauseButton -->
                    <s:ToggleButton id="playPauseButton" left="0" bottom="0" 
                            skinClass="spark.skins.spark.mediaClasses.normal.PlayPauseButtonSkin" 
                            skinClass.fullScreenStates="spark.skins.spark.mediaClasses.fullScreen.PlayPauseButtonSkin"
                            layoutDirection="ltr"
                            focusIn="event.target.depth=1" focusOut="event.target.depth=0" />

                    <!-- scrubbar + the currentTime/duration labels -->
                    <s:Group left="39" right="75" top="0" bottom="0">

                        <!-- background for scrubbar + the currentTime/duration -->
                        <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
                            <s:fill>
                                <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" color.fullScreenStates="0x585858" alpha.fullScreenStates="0.55"/>
                                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xDCDCDC" color.fullScreenStates="0x1E1E1E" alpha.fullScreenStates="0.55"/>
                                </s:LinearGradient>
                            </s:fill>
                        </s:Rect>

                        <!-- fill highlight  (exclude in fullScreen) -->
                        <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="1" height="11" excludeFrom="fullScreenStates">
                            <s:fill>
                                <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.3" />
                            </s:fill>
                        </s:Rect>

                        <!-- one pixel border -->
                        <s:Rect left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1">
                            <s:stroke>
                                <s:LinearGradientStroke weight="1" rotation="90">
                                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xFEFEFE" color.fullScreenStates="0xFFFFFF" alpha.fullScreenStates="0.12" />
                                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xEAEAEA" color.fullScreenStates="0xFFFFFF" alpha.fullScreenStates="0.09" />
                                </s:LinearGradientStroke>
                            </s:stroke>
                        </s:Rect>

                        <!-- border for the scrubbar/time label controls -->
                        <s:Rect left="-1" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
                            <s:stroke>
                                <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x131313" color.fullScreenStates="0x222222" alpha.fullScreenStates="0.66"  />
                            </s:stroke>
                        </s:Rect>

                        <!-- scrub bar + currentTime/duration in a HorizontalLayout -->
                        <s:Group left="0" right="0" height="23" bottom="0">
                            <s:layout>
                                <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle" gap="1" />
                            </s:layout>

                            <!-- spacer -->
                            <s:Rect width="7" height="1" />

                            <!--- @copy spark.components.VideoPlayer#scrubBar -->
<!--                            <s:ScrubBar id="scrubBar" width="100%" liveDragging="true"
                                skinClass="spark.skins.spark.mediaClasses.normal.ScrubBarSkin"
                                skinClass.fullScreenStates="spark.skins.spark.mediaClasses.fullScreen.ScrubBarSkin" />
-->                            
                            <!-- spacer -->
                            <s:Rect width="8" height="1" />

                            <!--- @copy spark.components.VideoPlayer#currentTimeDisplay -->
<!--                            <s:Label id="currentTimeDisplay" color.fullScreenStates="0xFFFFFF" />
-->                            
                            <!--- @private -->
  <!--                          <s:Label id="timeDivider" text="/" color.fullScreenStates="0xFFFFFF" />
  -->                          
                            <!--- @copy spark.components.VideoPlayer#durationDisplay -->
<!--                            <s:Label id="durationDisplay" color.fullScreenStates="0xFFFFFF" />
-->                            
                            <!-- spacer -->
                            <s:Rect width="8" height="1" />
                        </s:Group>

                    </s:Group>

                    <!--- @copy spark.components.VideoPlayer#volumeBar -->
                    <s:VolumeBar id="volumeBar" snapInterval=".01" stepSize=".01" liveDragging="true"
                            right="37" bottom="0" 
                            layoutDirection="ltr"
                            skinClass="spark.skins.spark.mediaClasses.normal.VolumeBarSkin"
                            skinClass.fullScreenStates="spark.skins.spark.mediaClasses.fullScreen.VolumeBarSkin"
                            focusIn="event.target.depth=1" focusOut="event.target.depth=0" />

                    <!--- @copy spark.components.VideoPlayer#fullScreenButton -->
<!--                    <s:Button id="fullScreenButton" right="0" bottom="0" label="Fullscreen" 
                            skinClass="spark.skins.spark.mediaClasses.normal.FullScreenButtonSkin"
                            skinClass.fullScreenStates="spark.skins.spark.mediaClasses.fullScreen.FullScreenButtonSkin"
                            focusIn="event.target.depth=1" focusOut="event.target.depth=0" />
-->                            
                </s:Group>

            </s:Group>

            <!-- border -->
            <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" excludeFrom="fullScreenStates">
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x131313" />
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Rect>

        </s:Group>
    </s:Group>
</s:SparkSkin>
```